# How to make one query to the database to find the date between, before, after and pageable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

```
If startDate not null and endDate not null = beetwen + pageable
If startDate is null and endDate not null = before + pageable
If startDate not null and endDate is null = after + pageable
```

I also wanted to use userIdentifier in the request, but I probably have to divide it into 2 requests when null and when with a value

I can't figure out how to come up with a request with these conditions

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM notification m WHERE :userIdentifier is null")
Flux<Notification> findAllByUserIdentifier(Timestamp startDate, Timestamp endDate, int page, 
int size);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to short circuit your query like this:

```java
@Query("SELECT n FROM notification n WHERE " +
"(:start is null or n.date >= :start) " + 
"and (:end is null or n.date <= :end) ")
Page<Notification> findAllByUserIdentifier(@Param("start") Timestamp startDate, @Param("end") Timestamp endDate, Pageable pageable);
```

Here we are checking for the conditions you want and using the filter only when the actual parameters are present, the `Pageable` parameter is an object that you will need to pass to the method to get a `Page` from the db. You can create that parameter like this: `PageRequest.of(page, size)` with page being the current page you want to query and size being the number of records to return.

The response `Page` will have the following methods for extracting the page values:

- `getTotalElements` gets the total element count for the query
- `getContent` gets the list of entities in selected by the query